# nodejs server - mac terminal crash every one hour

Tags: node.js, terminal

I got  a live server running nodejs chat app. I connect to server using terminal on mac. I start the server by typing server.js.

the problem is, my terminal always hung after one hour running, and there are no error outputs. when it hangs, I press ctrl+c I got the message [process completed].

note: My terminal runs node apps locally without any problems. 
And my current chat app run well when I initiate it with WinSCP in windows platform.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?  Can you post the code (or a link to it) that you are running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try launching your node process on the remote server using [a tool like nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

```bash
bash$ nohup /path/to/node server.js > out.txt 2> err.txt &
[1] 53032
# Now you can logout of the remote server without
#   killing the "node" process and chat server.
```

**[Edit]**

Note that the number printed by "nohup" (e.g. 53032) is the id of detached process, so if you need to terminate it you can do something like "`kill -9 53032`".  If you forgot to record that number then you'll have to find it by using a program such as "ps"; for example, you can run "`ps auxwww | grep node`" (the flags will vary depending on your system) and you'll see output similar to this:

```
maerics  81694   0.6  0.5  2543604  21216 s000  S+   10:34AM   0:09.45 /Users/maerics/opt/node/node server.js
```

In this example, on my system, the number in the second column is the process id.

Comment: Or perhaps just running it in [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Comment: I got a new problem. The terminal crashes, but It forgot to kill the server, now I don't how to stop the server.

Comment: @runrunforest: see my updated answer with information on how to kill it afterwards.

Comment: @mikl: add your comments as your own answer, those tools are also good solutions to OPs problem!